# Oracle SQL Developer question from newbie

Tags: sql, oracle, pivot

Sorry could not think of more descriptive title. I have data that looks like:

| MEMBERID | TICKETID | STATUS |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | 123 | Y |
| A | 012 | N |
| A | 456 | Y |
| B | XYZ | N |
| B | ABC | N |
| C | DEF | Y |
| C | 789 | Y |

I want to separate the above into three tables:
(1) Members that ONLY have tickets with Status=Y
(2) Members that have mixed status tickets (so at least one ticket with status=Y and at least one ticket with status=N)
(3) Members that ONLY have tickets with Status=N

In Excel I would just do a pivot table that results in something like:

| MEMBERID | "Y" | "N" |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | 2 | 1 |
| B | 0 | 2 |
| C | 2 | 0 |

...then add a 4th column with a formula that allows me to separate member IDs by "Only Y", "Only N", and "Y/N". I'm new to SQL though, and can't seem to get "pivot" to run correctly, or maybe there's a "where" clause that could resolve this without using pivot? Help!

Comment: I think GROUP option is for this.

Answer (score 1):

You could pivot but it's probably simpler to just do the aggregation yourself:

```
select memberid,
  count(case when status = 'Y' then ticketid end) as y,
  count(case when status = 'N' then ticketid end) as n
from your_table
group by memberid
order by memberid;
```

To get the fourth column you can either repeat the counts within another case expression:

```
select memberid,
  count(case when status = 'Y' then ticketid end) as y,
  count(case when status = 'N' then ticketid end) as n,
  case
    when count(case when status = 'Y' then ticketid end) > 0
      and count(case when status = 'N' then ticketid end) > 0
    then 'Y/N'
    when count(case when status = 'Y' then ticketid end) > 0
    then 'Only Y'
    when count(case when status = 'N' then ticketid end) > 0
    then 'Only N'
  end as yn
from your_table
group by memberid
order by memberid;
```

Or put the initial query into a CTE or inline view which is clearer and has less repetition, so easier to maintain:

```
select memberid, y, n,
  case
    when y > 0 and n > 0 then 'Y/N'
    when y > 0 then 'Only Y'
    when n > 0 then 'Only N'
  end as yn
from (
  select memberid,
    count(case when status = 'Y' then ticketid end) as y,
    count(case when status = 'N' then ticketid end) as n
  from your_table
  group by memberid
)
order by memberid;
```

Either way you end up with:

```
MEMBERID Y N YN
-------- - - ------
A        2 1 Y/N
B        0 2 Only N
C        2 0 Only Y
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/583ebf/3)

Comment: This worked wonderfully! Thank you so much!